# Audio files Android

Tags: java, android, audio, frequency-analysis

I wanted to know if there is a way to process an audio file via Android. in practice I would upload the audio file and change the bpm for example how does the software audacity. thank you

Comment: what kind of processing you need to do?

Comment: I have not yet defined but surely changing bpm @hanaa

Answer (score 0):

You might want to begin with [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

Comment: can I change bpm with this?

Comment: yes, just call setRate(): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html#setRate(int, float)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Have you tried it out?

Comment: with these parameters I could not take off frequency for example